# Persistence in MapReduce

Tags: persistence, mapreduce

Let's say you have divided your work for the map phase of map/reduce and mapping is running.  Now, each unit of work takes about 1 minute.  Let's say that you need to stop processing.  How would you persist the state of the map/reduce so that you waste the least amount of time when you start back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to memoize the results in a way that allows you to skip most of the processing of rows you've seen before.  If there's a candidate key that identifies the row you can use that to look in a cache, then fetch the processed results that are stored there.

Setting up your cluster with Memcached or Redis would be one approach for achieving memoization.